# Does an Incantatrix learn new spells per level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, prestige-class

This may be something I'm just missing, but it seems by a strict reading, the Incantatrix (I also checked the Mystic Theurge, I'm assuming some of the other prestige classes), no longer get the two free spells per level known added to their spellbook. Is this the case? Would those fall under 'other benefits of that (base) class?'

> An incantatrix continues to study standard magic as well as pursuing studies in metamagic. Thus, when a new incantatrix level is gained, the character gains **new spells per day** as if she had also gained a level in a spellcasting class she belonged to before becoming an incantatrix. She does not, however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have gained (bonus metamagic or item creation feats, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Technically, No.

You have already quoted the important information. Gaining new spells per day is not the same as learning new spells.

[SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/) **for wizard states:**

> Spellbooks
>
> At each new wizard level, she gains two new spells of any spell level or levels that she can cast (based on her new wizard level) for her spellbook. At any time, a wizard can also add spells found in other wizards’ spellbooks to her own.

**Using Archmage for an example:**

> Spells per Day/Spells Known
>
> When a new archmage level is gained, the character gains new spells per day (and spells known, if applicable) as if he had also gained a level in whatever arcane spellcasting class in which he could cast 7th-level spells before he added the prestige class level. He does not, however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have gained.

But I haven't met any DM's that actually enforce that. I, as DM, don't enforce it either. Besides, even if you do enforce it, it isn't anything that can't be overcome with some gold and scrolls.

If access to that is difficult, then consider feats that adds spells to lists, and the [Ancestral Relic](http://dndtools.pw/feats/book-of-exalted-deeds--52/ancestral-relic--70/) feat that would allow you to [pimp your spellbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=9271.45;wap2).

Comment: The *Dragon* #289 Sage Advice column says that appropriate prestige classes "do add spells to their lists [of known spells]. For example, a wizard/loremaster gains 2 spells for her spellbook when using a loremaster level to increasing spellcasting.... Adding spells to your spellbook or personal repertoire [like a sorcerer does] is part of spellcasting" (118). But this source is game-ancient (Nov. 2001). Does this stance change officially later in the game's development?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sage advice is similar to Customer Service and has the same history of wrong and sometimes contradictory advice. As stated, I have never been with a DM that went along with that. The FAQ on Paizo, regarding Pathfinder, actually go along with this ruling.

Comment: I was more concerned with finding that source that made the Sage Advice contradictory or wrong. I mean, I agree that adding spells to one's spellbook should *not* count as spellcasting, but, at one point, Sage Advice said it *did* count. I was just wondering if there was a *later* source than an old Sage Advice column that said *for sure* it didn't count. It's cool if there's not.

Comment: I will do some research on it. I will say this: The Ultimate Magus and Master Specialist have adding new spells to their spellbooks as a class feature. Those are also newer prestige classes - especially considering how old Loremaster is. That _may_ have been WotC's attempt of countering their mistake with other arcane prestige classes not adding spells to a spellbook. However, the 2 gained per level should not be the only way an arcane spellcaster should rely upon expanding their spellbook.